# How to generate CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I need some pointers/advice on how to automatically generate CMakeLists.txt files for CMake. Does anyone know of any existing generators? I've checked the ones listed in the [CMake Wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake#Basic_CMakeLists.txt_from-scratch-generator) but unfortunately they are not suitable for me.

I already have a basic Python script which traverses my project's directory structure and generates the required files but it's really "dumb" right now. I would like to augment it to take into account for example the different platforms I'm building for, the compiler\cross-compiler I'm using or different versions of the libraries dependencies I might have. I don't have much\expert experience with CMake and an example I could base my work or an already working generator could be of great help.

Comment: It should be really dumb.  You really don't want code that does directory traversal knowing about platforms or anything sophisticated.  Isolate that code in project level configuration.

Comment: @Tom K I'm not doing platform specific directory traversal, just inside my project structure which will be the same regardless the platform. I don't see why that would pose problems. I need to select\deselect some options, include dirs etc. based on the actual platform I'm building for.

Comment: I would suggest that you consider [Premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) instead of CMake. They both do more or less the same thing, but where CMake build files are simple data, Premake build files are _scripts_ (specifically Lua scripts). So you have all the power of a scripting language in your build configuration files. Directory iteration (cross-platform), conditional branching (doing A on one platform, B on another), etc is all available to you.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas CMake has its own scripting language. You can have conditional and the likes inside the CMake files, so it's scriptable to some extent.Unfortunately I cannot switch to Premake.

Comment: If you want to select/deselect include directories based on platform, you just do IF(WIN32) INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(...) ENDIF() or something. You can of course use more generic platform tests based on  ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} for example

Comment: @Vladislav Vaintroub I'm aware I can do that from inside the CMakeLists.txt file. I want to automatically generate that file, that is I want to automatically generate the conditionals you mention(or something on the lines of that).

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering what do you want to accomplish. It is rather hard to understand without having an example. In my experience with CMake, generating CMakeLists.txt was never necessary. For me use cases would be either converting it from another build system e.g autotools, or dumb traversing directories, like TomK mentioned.

Comment: @Vladislav Vaintroub I work with a common code base from which I build a shared library for Windows and Linux for x86 and ARM processors. It may happen that someone adds a feature to the shared lib which requires different implementation files depending on the platform\processor. That would require to modify some of the CMakeLists.txt files by hand to add the paltform checks and anything else required. I want to provide an automatic way of doing that if possible - the programmer implementing the feature would have to just execute a script that would reconfigure the necessary CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @Vladislav Vaintroub - I see more and more the fact that what I want to do might be futile and without any real benefit, as CMake is already a generator by itself - a generator of Makefiles - so it might be nonsensical to generate the generator. But if anyone has done that or at least tried that, I would like to know about it, maybe look at its implementation, learn from that and, eventually if in the end it makes sense, try to implement this kind of functionality by myself.

Comment: Actually, after refactoring a few buildsystems .. i have found that its best to leave CMakeLists.txt to include the full, dumb listing of all the source files, and make the source files themselves include the necessary compile guards. So, all your Linux, windows, ARM etc specific files are always compiled/included in the project, but the source files themselves have preprocessor conditionals excluding them from build. So you can almost always go "gcc -I. *.cpp" in any given directory.
If thats not an option, you have to manually do your if's in cmakelists.txt

Comment: And another hopefully helpful tip : if you generate full file listings by dumb python script in earch dir, say "files.cmake" and have CMakeLists.txt everywhere just do "include(files)" at the top, you can post-edit the generated lists in cmake script.
So if your files.cmake creates a CMake variable SOURCES, just do
if(win32) list(remove SOURCES posix-specific-code.cpp) endif()

Comment: @kert that last piece of information is a gem :). Do you have any web links to pages describing such features? I find the CMake documentation to be very hard to chew and rather dull(don't have the possibility to buy their book). I keep digging into it and finding things like the ones you mention above but it's a slow process. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Dont have particular links that you wouldnt already know, but ive learned cmake through practice, pouring over docs, referring the mailing list, looking at enough cmake code examples on code.google.com, and testing the behavior in small sample projects.
 
The important bit to realize is that CMake script _IS_ a language, and you can do tons of things with it that may not be immediately obvious. For instance i've converted a few sed/awk scripts used in previous autotools codebase to be purely cmake scripts and hence truly crossplatform.
It is a slow learning process, good luck

Answer (score 25):

I am of the opinion that you need not use an automated script for generating CMakeLists.Txt as it is a very simple task to write one, after you have understood the basic procedure. Yeah I do agree that understanding the procedure to write one as given in CMake Wiki is also difficult as it is too much detailed.

A very basic example showing how to write *CMakeLists.txt* is shown [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20141116113322/http://preetisblog.com/programming/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt), which I think will be of use to everyone, even someone who is going to write CMakeLists.txt for the first time.

Comment: Website is down. There is [cached link version](http://web.archive.org/web/20141116113322/http://preetisblog.com/programming/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: No matter how well you understand the procedure, generating one automatically will always be faster and more convenient. This question deserves a useful answer.

Comment: That URL now redirects...
[Thanks, Wayback...](https://web.archive.org/web/20170814005007/http://preetisblog.com/programming/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt/)

Comment: I'm working on a project with thousands of source files in CLion. I don't want to add all new files created by someone else and remove all deleted files manually after every git pull...

Comment: Not only is this a non-answer, but even if it were, it's a _link-only_ post, which now points to a car site. This shows everything that's wrong with these kinds of posts.

Comment: @code_dredd Not true, the answer is "write it by hand". You just don't want to hear that.

Answer (score 21):

Well i dont have much of an experience in Cmake either, but to perform a cross platform make a lot of files need to be written and modified including the CMakeLists.txt file, i suggest that you use this new tool called the ProjectGenerator Tool, its pretty cool, it does all the extra work needed and makes it easy to generate such files for 3'rd party sources with little effort.
Just read the README carefully before using it.

Link:
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=54842

Comment: This is actually the only post answering the question. I dont think it should be downvoted just because folks personall preference is to do things manually, because linux.

Comment: @David: Agree, but that's not the only post answering the question anymore, I added one!

Comment: Note that this "ProjectGenerator Tool" is apparently discontinued. Provided links in the forum are broken.

Answer (score 10):

I'm maintaining a C++ software environment that has more than 1000 modules (shared, static libraries, programs) and uses more than 20 third parties (boost, openCV, Qt, Qwt...). This software environment hosts many programs (~50), each one picking up some libraries, programs and third parties. I use CMake to generate the makefiles and that's really great.

However, if you write your `CMakeLists.txt` as it is recommended to do (declare the module as being a library/program, importing source files, adding dependencies...). I agree with celavek: maintaining those `CMakeLists.txt` files is a real pain:

- When you add a new file to a module, you need to update its `CMakeLists.txt`
- When you upgrade a third party, you need to update the `CMakeLists.txt` of all modules using it
- When you add a new dependency (library `A` now needs library `B`), you may need to update the `CMakeLists.txt` of all programs using `A`
- When you want a new global settings to be changed (compiler setting, predefined variable, C++ standard used), you need to update all your `CMakeLists.txt`

Then, I see two strategies to adress those issues and likely the one mentioned by OP.

**1- Have `CMakeLists.txt` be well written and be smart enough not to have a frozen behaviourto update themselves on the fly**. That's what we have in our software environment. Each module has a standardized file organization (sources are in `src` folder, includes are in `inc` folder...) and have simple text files to specify their dependencies (with keywords we defined, like `QT` to say the module needs to link with `Qt`). Then, our `CMakeLists.txt` is a two-line file and simply calls a cmake macro we wrote to automatically setup the module. As a MCVE that would be:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
include( utl.cmake )
add_module( "mylib", lib )
```

utl.cmake:

```
macro( add_module name what )
    file(GLOB_RECURSE source_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
    if ( what STREQUEL "lib" )
        add_library( ${name} SHARED ${source_files} )
    elseif ( what STREQUEL "prg" )
        add_executable( ${name} ${source_files} )
    endif()
    # TODO: Parse the simple texts files to add target_link_libraries accordingly
endmacro()
```

Then, for all situations exposed above, you simply need to update utl.cmake, not the thousand of `CMakeLists.txt` you have...

Honestly, we are very happy with this approach, the system becomes very easy to maintain and we can easily add new dependencies, upgrade third parties, change some build/dependency strategies...

However, there remains a lot of `CMake` scripts to be written. And `CMake` script language sucks...the tool's very powerful, right, but the script's variable scope, the cache, the painful and not so well documented syntax (just to check if a list is empty you must ask for it's size and store this in a variable!), the fact it's not object oriented...make it a real pain to maintain.

So, I'm now convinced the real good approach may be to:

**2- completly generate the `CMakeLists.txt`** from a more powerful language like Python. The Python script would do things similar to what our utl.cmake does, instead it would generate a `CMakeLists.txt` ready to be passed CMake tool (with a format as proposed in HelloWorld, no variable, no function....it would only call standard CMake function).

I doubt such generic tool exists, because it's hard to produce the `CMakeLists.txt` files that will make everyone happy, you'll have to write it yourself. Note that [gen-cmake](https://github.com/astavonin/gen-cmake) does that (generates a CMakeLists.txt), but in a very primitive way and it apparently only supports Linux, but it may be a good start point.

This is likely to be the v2 of our software environment...one day.

Note : Additionally, if you want to support both qmake and cmake for instance, a well written Python script could generate both CMakeLists and pro files on demand!

Comment: Doesn't targets solve most of the problems with having to keep dependencies ?

Comment: @LuizFelipe: What do you mean by "targets"?

Comment: I mean this https://hsf-training.github.io/hsf-training-cmake-webpage/04-targets/index.html

Answer (score 9):

I think that you are doing this upside down.

When using CMake, you are supposed to write the CMakeLists.txt yourself. Typically, you don't need to handle different compilers as CMake has knowledge about them. However, if you must, you can add code in the CMakeFiles to do different things depending on the tool you are using.

Comment: I concur. CMake is the best such build tool I've used, but you have to play by its rules, and be disciplined with your sources' physical design. You're probably best off looking at how CMake is used in other Python projects.

Comment: Typically when using cross-compilers it's not as easy as it probably should be. And I'm writing most of my CMakeLists.txt files myself, I just needed a little help to "maintain" in an more or less automated fashion the list of files I need to include in the build - I have hundreds of source files and making sure everything is fine and dandy by hand is quite error prone and time consuming. Anyway I made the script I already had a little bit less dumb and with the help of the comments from @kert I actually have something which pretty much works as I required.

Comment: That would be true if there wasn't a lot of stupid CMake scripts written like Makefiles with lots of IFs and global variables that you need to rewrite to CMake20 (done right (TM).

Answer (score 9):

[CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) is an Integrated development environment that is fully based on CMake project file.

It is able to generate itself the CMakeLists.txt file when using the **import project from source**

However this is quite probable that you have to edit this file manually as your project grows and for adding external dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for such a generator but at the end I decided to write my own (partly because I wanted to understand how CMake works):

https://github.com/Aenteas/cmake-generator

It has a couple of additional features such as creating python wrappers (SWIG).

Writing a generator that suits everyone is impossible but I hope it will give you an idea in case you want to make your customized version.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is a problem original poster faced, but as I see plenty of „just write CMakefile.txt” answers above, let me shortly explain why generating CMakefiles may make sense:

a) I have another build system I am fairly happy with

(and which covers large multiplatform build of big collection
    of interconnected shared and static libraries, programs, scripting
    language extensions, and tools, with various internal and external
    dependencies, quirks and variants)

b) Even if I were to replace it, I would not consider cmake.

I took a look at CMakefiles and I am not happy with the syntax
   and not happy with the semantics.

c) CLion uses CMakefiles, and Cmakefiles only (and seems somewhat interesting)

So, to give CLion a chance (I love PyCharm, so it's tempting), but to keep using my build system, I would gladly use some tool which would let me
implement
    make generate_cmake
and have all necessary CMakefiles generated on the fly according to the current
info extracted from my build system. I can gladly feed the tool/script with information which sources and headers my app consists of, which libraries and programs it is expected to build, which -I, -L, -D, etc are expected to be set for which component, etc etc.

*Well, of course I would be much happier if JetBrains would allow to provide some direct protocol of feeding the IDE with the information it needs
(say, allowed me to provide my own command to compile, to run, and to
emit whatever metadata they really need - I suppose they mainly need incdirs and defines to implement on the fly code analysis, and libpaths to setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the debugger), without referring to cmake. CMakefiles as protocol are somewhat complicated.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be helpful:

https://conan.io/

The author has given some speeches about cmake and how to create modular projects using cmake into CPPCon. As far as I know, this tool require cmake, so that I suppose that generate it when you integrate new packages, or create new packages. Recently I read something about how to write a higher level description of the C/C++ project using a YAML file, but not sure if it is part of conan or not (what I read was from the author of conan). I have never used, and it is something pending for me, so that, please if you use it and fit your needs, comment your opinions about it and how it fit your scenario.