# Are cmake scripts generally written by hand?

Tags: cmake

I need to create a cmake project which should be able to be built on linux and windows. So I looked into cmake Tutorials and all of them told me to setup the build process by hand. Bit looking at other projects made with cmake, the scripts seam like they were created by a computer (no formatting no comments). So I was wondering if there was a more automated aproach or tool that can be used for cmake files. Or are most cmake scripts really written by hand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate CMakeLists.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914524/how-to-generate-cmakelists-txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `CMakeLists.txt` are generally written by hand. Generated are `SomeProjectConfig.cmake` modules, which contain exported targets and information how the project was built. These modules are used by `find_package` command when you want to use `SomeProject` from your own project.